# Integer division in Angular2 expression

Tags: angular

How to perform an integer division in Angular2 expression?
I know there is number:0 filter but it transforms to the closest full number and I want to just get rid of the fraction.
Like:

```
{{100/60}}
```

Displaying just 1.

Comment: the code you presented should work as expected

Comment: not really, it displays the fraction

Comment: what are you after then?

Comment: i don't want to display the fraction, "integer division"

Comment: so you want to display `1` or `1 remainder 60`?

Comment: just 1, single full number

Comment: see my answer, there is a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is a way. It will return you the whole number, the opposite of modulo `%`

```
{{ (x / y) - (( x % y ) / y) }}
```

this will display what you want without pipes or functions or anything extra

Comment: Weird, it shows 0.99999... instead o 1, why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Little improvement: only one division and sure to get integer:

> ```
> {{ ((x - (x % y)) / y) }}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `Math.floor(y/x)` in javascript:

`Math.floor(100/60)`